# Condensation points

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I've shown previously that in a separable metric space the set condensation points has no isolation points and is perfect. In a separable metric space $\left(X,d\right)$, the set of condensation points of $X$ is denoted as $\operatorname{cond}\left(X\right)$. How can I show that $\operatorname{cond}\left(\operatorname{cond}\left(X\right)\right)=\operatorname{cond}\left(X\right)$?

Comment: All this holds for separable metric spaces but not for general metric spaces.

Comment: @WlodAA, oops you're right. I forgot to mention that this metric space is separable.

Comment: If $N$ is the set of all non-condensation points of a set $S$ (in a separable metric space) then $S\cap N$ is countable. Now $\operatorname{cond}(S)\supseteq S\setminus(S\cap N),$ and every condensation point of $S$ is also a condensation point of $S\setminus(S\cap N)$ since $S\cap N$ is countable.

Comment: More generally, instead of a separable metric space, this works in a second countable topological space, or more generally still, a hereditarily Lindelof topological space.

Comment: @bof: For those interested, I posted some basic relationships and counterexamples for these notions in [this 9 October 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/plaintext.jspa?messageID=5229844) archived at Math Forum. Probably bof knows this stuff, but I figured he/she might be interested anyway. (I'm not positive, but I think the Math Forum discussion groups archive is being taken down at the end of December, so print this out if you want it for later use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A separable metric space is  hereditarily  Lindelof.

Suppose (by way of contradiction) that $p\in cond(X)\setminus cond(cond(X)).$ Let  $U$ be open with $p\in U$.

For brevity let $S= U\setminus cond(X).$ For $y\in S$ let $y\in  B(y)\subset U$ where $B(y)$ is open and countable.  Now $\{B(y)\cap S:y\in S\}$ is a countable open cover of the Lindelof sub$space$ $S$, so there exists countable $T\subset S$ such that $\cup \{B(y):y\in T\}\supset S.$  Therefore $S=U\cap S$ is  countable ( because $S$ is a  subset of the countable set $\cup \{B(y):y\in T\}$).

Now $U$ is uncountable because $p\in cond(X)$, and $U =(U \setminus S)\cup (U\cap S),$ with $U\cap S$ countable. So $U\setminus S=U\setminus (U\setminus cond (S))=U\cap cond(S)$ is uncountable. But this means that any open $U$ containing   $p$ has uncountable intersection with $cond(X),$ so $p\in cond(cond(X)),$ a contradiction.

We conclude that $cond(X)\subset cond(cond (X)).$ The reverse inclusion $cond(X)\supset cond(cond(X)$ is easy and I leave it to you.

Remark: If $(X,d)$ is a separable metric space and $D$ is a countable dense subset of $X$ then $B=\{B_d(x,q):x\in D\} \land q\in \Bbb Q^+\}$ is a countable base (basis) for $X,$ so $X$ is Lindelof. And if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ then $\{b\cap Y:b\in B\}$ is a countable base for $Y,$ so $Y$ is also Lindelof.

Comment: Why is $S$ Lindelof? Doesn't $S$ need to be closed to be guaranteed to be Lindelof? And could you explain the last sentence of the first paragraph: "Therefore $S=U\cap S$..." Everything else I understand.

Comment: $S$ is a sub-space of the 2nd-countable space $X$ so $S$ is 2nd-countable so  any open cover of $S$ has a countable sub-cover......I had a typo.  The last expression in the 1st paragraph should have been $\cup \{B(y):y\in T\}.$.. (which is a countable union of countable sets, and covers $S$, so $S$ is countable. And $S=U\cap S$ by def'n of $S$, but it might be better to mention that later, when we get  to $U=(U$ \ $S)\cup (U\cap S)$.

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks!